# Help me understand arithmetics?!

Tags: trigonometry

here is the main question:
*I wanna know why Cosine of a given angle is equal to adjacent "divided" by hypotenuse? (same for sine).

And about trig functions, 
This is what i understood so far :
These two functions are for finding height and width of a given angle.

for example, rotating a vector by a given angle would be like this:
vector's x = cos(angle)
vector's y = sine(angle)
and in 3D the x and y could change when we use euler rotation.
And i still get confused when a trig function is involved..

Comment: To answer your main question: By definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, the gradient sequence of concepts you need to understand are:

- What are "similar triangles" (triangles with the same shape but of different size)
- The fact the corresponding angles of similar triangles are equal.
- The fact that the *ratio* of any two specific sides is equal from one triangle to a similar triangle.

That last one is a bit of a jump; you can back it up like so:

- The concept of a ratio.
- The concept of equal ratios.
- The concept of equal ratios as four numbers (two numerators and two denominators), which can be turned any which way and still form an equation.

For example:

$\frac 9 {21} = \frac {15} {35}$

$\frac {21} {35} = \frac 9 {15}$

$\frac {35} {15} = \frac {21} {9}$

$\frac {15} {9} = \frac {35} {21}$

If you have that, then the earlier concept I mentioned will make more sense:

- The fact that the *ratio* of any two specific sides is equal from one triangle to a similar triangle.

For example, take two similar triangles.  One is the smaller triangle, one is the larger triangle.  Each has a short side, a medium side, and a long side.  (They could have all sides equal, or two sides equal, but this is just an example.)

By definition of "similar triangle," the ratio of the short side of the small triangle to the short side of the large triangle is the *same* as the ratio of the long side of the small triangle to the long side of the large triangle.  That's what "similar triangles" *means.*

By the principle of equal ratios as illustrated above, you can also see that the ratio of the short side of the small triangle to the long side of the small triangle is the *same* as the ratio of the short side of the large triangle to the long side of the large triangle.

Got all that?  Okay, great.

Now for the big jump:

All right triangles that have a 37 degree angle are similar to all other right triangles that have a 37 degree angle.

Therefore, in any particular right triangle which has a 37 degree angle, the ratio of the smallest side to the hypotenuse will be the same as the ratio of the smallest side to the hypotenuse in *any* other right triangle with a 37 degree angle.

Likewise, in any particular right triangle with a 74 degree angle, the ratio of the side opposite the 74 degree angle, to the side opposite the 90 degree angle (the hypotenuse), will be the same as that ratio in any other right triangle with a 74 degree angle.

If you have all that, then you will understand that **sine, cosine and tangent are just names for particular ratios of sides in right triangles.**

The ratios I just described in my two triangle examples can be referred to much more concisely by saying:

sine 37°

and:

sine 74°

The meaning is the same.